# Recovering deleted records from ibdata1

Tags: innodb

Is it possible to recover deleted rows from ibdata1? I have only ibdata1 file and no other files or tables. I want to recover all table structures and datas with deleted records. Is it possible ?

Comment: It is not a dublicate question. In my senario there are no other files like. frm or iblogs. I just have ibdata1 file and no table structures or any other information. I need to recreate tables and recover all datas with deleted rocerds

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could you supply us with more information? Have you tried starting the instance? Are the files where they used to be or just files in a directory? What have you tried so far? The more information you provide us with the easier it is for the community to assist you. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and would probably be closed, because it [Needs detail or clarity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: I copied ibdata1 file from innodb engine. There is no other table or file that i have handled. My purpose is to learn how to recover tables and datas from ibdata1 file. Is it possible or not ? If it possible how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to recover deleted rows from ibdata1?

Probably not.

> My purpose is to learn how to recover tables and data from ibdata1 file.

You *should not* be trying to do so.

That file is in a *proprietary* format might could, potentially, *change* between DBMS versions.

In order to *Restore* anything about a database, you should be working with the *Backup* tools relevant to your DBMS.  Trying to glean anything from the shattered remains of a broken database file is a Fools Errand.